# Python index error: attribute error:'nametype' object has no attribute'findALL'

Tags: python, linux

I'm a beginner and I keep receiving an error on pycharm in ubuntu.

The code is like this:

```py
Value = table.findAll('td')[1].text.split(' ')[0].strip()
```

and the error I'm getting is

```
attribute error:'nametype' object has no attribute'findALL'
```

Why is it wrong? Thanks everyone

Comment: Is it NoneType, instead of NameType?

Comment: Please specify the code, in which you are getting this error.

Comment: I am working on ubuntu into pycharm....python3....thanks

Comment: attribute error:'nametype' object has no attribute'findALL'

Comment: name type error :  findALL        WHY?

Comment: Please give the code in which you are facing this error

Comment: no code....its shows...attribute error:'nametype' object has no attribute'findALL'

Comment: Please include the **exact** error message you are getting, character-for-character. Instead, it seems you have attempted to transcribe the error and ended up with something similar but not exactly the same, and this is unhelpful. There is (as far as I know) no such type as `nametype`, `AttributeError` is one word and there is no reason for `findALL` to have two capital `L`s other than by you manually introducing this error.

Comment: As for why you are getting this error, it seems you are doing something with Selenium or BeautifulSoup and are looking for a table that either (a) hasn't loaded yet (in Selenium) or (b) doesn't exist at all, but you didn't bother to check whether this table was actually found and have attempted to proceed regardless. Of course, this is only a guess based on the single line of code you provided us with.

Comment: I am doing load selenium & Beautifulsoup and nametype is findAll but as I have error attribute error:'nametype' object has no attribute'findAll'